# Handling the string "null" as an Object in Java

Tags: java, string, object, null

I have tweets stored in a MongoDB database, and am pulling them out to do some analysis.

In this instance, I'm looking at the hashtags associated with the tweet, and using the following code:

```
BasicDBList hts = (BasicDBList)obj.get(Constants.HASHTAGS_STR);
if (!hts.isEmpty())
    tb.setHashtags(hts.toArray(new String[0]));
```

This works perfectly... until I came across a tweet which used the word "null" as a hashtag.

In that case, the hts array is:

```
[  null ]
```

The hashtags are stored in a TreeSet internally, and the insert fails on the compare.  I don't want to discard this hashtag by doing a comparison to null - is there a better workaround?

The string literal "null" is stored in the database. The problem occurs when the BasicDBList reads it out as an Object, and that object is converted to a String. The String becomes a null string, instead of the String "null".  I want to understand how to get the data interpreted correctly, such that

```
tb.setHashtags()
```

results in tb having a hashtag "null" associated with it, instead of an error being thrown.

Comment: Uhh, `"null"` (a string) is *not* the `null` value. The 4-letter string will work just fine with `equals`.

Comment: There is nothing special about a String `"null"`, just compare it like you would any other string.

Comment: Also, `new String[0]` is an empty array, not null.

Comment: Null is usually not null. I mean you do not see the null literal if it is dbnull. Try to probe for dbnull

Comment: @ElliotFrisch Look up [`Collection.toArray(T[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray(T[])).

Comment: @shmosel What's your point? Elliot is perfectly correct. Collections.toArray() doesn't change that.

Comment: @EJP Elliot seems to be saying that the array could not not contain a `null` element if it is empty. My point was that passing an empty array doesn't necessarily mean you'll receive an empty array.

Comment: The string literal "null" is stored in the database.  The problem occurs when the BasicDBList reads it out as an Object, and that object is converted to a String.  The Sting becomes a null string, instead of the String "null".

Comment: Additionally, in the thousands of instances where I do have actual null values stored in the DB, the code works correctly.  This is an edge case.

Answer (score 0):

Verify whether the List (BasicDBList)hts contains Null values.

The method toArray is inherited from ArrayList, which may return an Array containing Null values.

Have a look at [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray(T%5B%5D)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29)

Comment: I included the contents of the BasicDBList above.  In instances where the list actually contains null, it appears as [], not [ null ]

Comment: you are using the instance of class BasicDBList which inherits the method toArray from ArrayList. In this method an array of type same as the parameter sent [here new String[0]], would be created and its size may vary based on the list items. The number of list items might not same as the array length, so the remaining indeces must have a null. You don't need to worry about the string literal "null", obviously its a string.

Comment: for your understanding just try to check, the length of list 'hts' and the length of the array returned by 'hts.toArray(new String[0])'

Comment: I appreciate the explanation, but you are missing my point. The problem is that the actual value in the database is the string "null". BasicDBList reads out an Object. When converting to String, it interprets it as the null value instead of the String literal.